# Latex Beamer, color text as example text

Tags: beamer

Is it possible in Beamer to color a text as the same color of example text?
Like doing `\example{text}` in the same way of `\alert{text}`?

I know we can do `\textcolor{example text.fg}{text}` but `\example{text}` is simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define yourself a macro that acts the same way than `\alert` (but don't name it `\example`, that's already taken my the environment of the same name)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}


\newenvironment<>{exenv}{\begin{altenv}#1%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{example text}}
      {}{\color{.}}{}\ignorespaces}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\ex}[1]{\begin{exenv}#2\relax#1\end{exenv}}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{example}
  content...
  \end{example}

  \ex{test}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```